# How to detect a word on Safari using js?

Tags: javascript, safari, v8

In Chrome, `Intl.v8BreakIterator` works fine.
Is there an alternative for this API on Safari?

Answer (score 0):

There's a standardized alternative in the works called `Intl.Segmenter`, but it's not ready yet. See the [repository](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-segmenter), or the [rendered spec text](https://tc39.es/proposal-intl-segmenter/).